# How to retrieve last inserted ID in golang go orm when using Raw query

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using a raw query to create an entry in MySQL,

```
db.Exec("INSERT STATEMENT")
```

I want to retrieve the last ID , in the native golang/sql package, it is easy, but  here in GORM I can't see anything

> I know that using the db.Create can solve my problem, but I have to use Raw query and nothing else

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to do it with GORM if you are not actually using GORM, but a raw query anyway? GORM [exposes the generic database interface](https://gorm.io/docs/generic_interface.html) through the `DB` method. So you can do this:

```
sqlDB, err := db.DB()

res, err := sqlDB.Exec("INSERT STATEMENT")

lid, err := res.LastInsertId()
```

Of course, you should handle possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

after your insert you can retrieve the ID in this way:

```
var lastId int
err = db.QueryRow("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").Scan(&lastId)
if err != nil {

}
fmt.Println(lastId)
```